# ssh to Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server behind firewall

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, firewall

I ssh to an Amazon EC2 server and have just enabled the ufw firewall. This terminated my connection and now I can't ssh back in. I assume the firewall is preventing access.

I tried rebooting but no help

Anyone have any ideas how I might be able to regain control of the server?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question, but the answer is: you can't.

You've killed Port 22 access to the VM with the firewall, and EC2 does not allow hypervisor root access to the console from where you might reconfigure (or disable) the firewall.

Next time, write the Port 22 rule into the firewall config BEFORE enabling it.